# Изменение цвета фона bg окна на странице после ввода цифр

Tags: javascript

Как изменить цвет bg при нужных мне значениях?

Пример:

У меня есть окно по середине страницы.

В этом окне есть текстовое поле.

При вводе в это поле значения по типу 432 (ключевая 1 четверка) цвет самого окна(НЕ СТРАНИЦЫ) меняется на желтый

Если это значение 5, на красный. (532)
И т.д.

Вот пример tinkoff.ru/cardtocard

Не понимаю как это реализовать.

Comment: пример вашей верстки в студию

Comment: собственно в чем конкретно проблема?. вы не знаете как задать `background-color ` ? или не знаете как из числа первую цифру получить? или не знаете как 10-ти цифрам сопоставить цвета?

Comment: Приветствую.
Я слабо знаком с JS в принципе. По этому не понимаю как сделать такую функцию.

Еще раз. Суть функции в том, что мне нужно изменение bg-color в зависимости от введенного текста в (текстовое)окно.
4-yellow
5-red
6-green
(Это все по первым цифрам)
Надеюсь понятно изъясняюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый тупой пример и на jQuery..

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){
  let val = $(this).val()[0], color = '#fff';
  if(val == 0) color = '#fff';
  if(val == 1) color = 'red';
  if(val == 2) color = 'blue';
  if(val == 3) color = 'rgba(223,123,231,.2)';
  if(val == 4) color = 'rgb(0,119,255)';
  if(val == 5) color = 'yellow';
  if(val == 6) color = 'green';
  if(val == 7) color = 'url(https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/abstract-polygonal-space-low-poly-dark-background-3d-rendering_7247-223.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover';
  if(val == 8) color = 'linear-gradient(45deg, #EECFBA, #C5DDE8)';
  if(val == 9) color = 'radial-gradient(40% 50%, #FAECD5, #CAE4D8)';
  $('body').css('background', color);
});
```

```css
body {margin: 0; min-height: 100vh; padding: 5px; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" value="0">
```

---

UPD

> **Взято из интернета**
>   2 - Мир
>   3 - American Express, JCB International, Diners Club
>    30,36,38 - Diners Club
>    31,35 - JCB International
>    34,37 - American Express
>   4 - VISA
>   5 - MasterCard, Maestro
>    50,56,57,58 - Maestro
>    51,52,53,54,55 - MasterCard
>   6 - Maestro, China UnionPay, Discover
>    60 - Discover
>    62 - China UnionPay
>    63,67 - Maestro
>   7 - УЭК

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  let id1 = parseInt($(this).val()[0]), id2 = parseInt($(this).val()[1]), card = '';
  switch (id1) {
    case 2: card = 'mir'; break;
    case 3:
     switch (id2) {
       case 0:
        case 6:
        case 8: card = 'diners'; break;
       case 1:
        case 5: card = 'jcb'; break;
       case 4:
        case 7: card = 'american_express'; break;
       default: card = '';
      }
      break;
    case 4: card = 'visa'; break;
    case 5:
     switch (id2) {
       case 0:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8: card = 'maestro'; break;
       case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5: card = 'master_card'; break;
       default: card = '';
      }
      break;
    case 6:
      switch (id2) {
       case 0: card = 'discover'; break;
       case 2: card = 'china_unionpay'; break;
       case 3:
        case 7: card = 'maestro'; break;
       default: card = '';
      }
      break;
    case 7: card = 'uec'; break;
    default: card = '';
  }
  $('.card').attr('class', 'card '+card)
});
```

```css
.card {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.card.mir {background: red;}
.card.diners {background: gray;}
.card.jcb {background: blue;}
.card.american_express {background: green;}
.card.visa {background: yellow;}
.card.maestro {background: black;}
.card.discover {background: violet;}
.card.china_unionpay {background: pink;}
.card.uec {background: aqua;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <input type="text" value="0000 0000 0000 0000">
</div>
```

P.s. советую ещё прочитать вот [эту](https://medium.com/@rofldorf/%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-865e7c5b0678) статью про карты.

Comment: и действительно, там где можно написать `switch` или завести массив, использовать кучу ифоф достойно вашего описания.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло, но от части.
Мне так же нужно, что-бы при "nnnn nnnn nnnn nnnn" - цвет менялся.

Изначально все подразумевалось как окно в виде пластиковой карты. При вводе номера карты - цвет окна для карты меняется под цвет банка. Visa - желтый
MC - красный
И дальше в том же роде.

Вопрос в том, как сделать это для других значений?
Т.к. если  я просто добавлю if(val == 432) color = '#fff'; , то скрипт будет работать по if(val == 4) color = 'yellow';

Comment: Вот пример

https://www.tinkoff.ru/cardtocard/